# How to tag schools in OpenStreetMap?

Tags: openstreetmap

How can we tag schools? One problem is that they are based on large areas, and there are entrances and barriers.

How can we handle footways or all the parts of a footway or service road from the main road network so that it is possible to route to the entrance of the school. Any ideas here?

Is it right that generally speaking school buildings can be tagged with `building=school`?

Comment: I think the detail level of this question is such that it would be far better answered on the http://help.openstreetmap.org Q & A site or on one of the OSM mailing lists. They will always be someone chiming in with an opinion over there! Happy to be proved wrong though!

Answer (score 3):

As Stev_k says, [help.openstreetmap.org](http://help.openstreetmap.org/) is probably a better place to ask this question but, broadly speaking you tag the area of the school as `amenity=school` and then tag building, paths etc in the same way you would anywhere they appeared.

So you might tag buildings as `building=yes` or `building=school`, paths as `highway=footway` and so on.

There is also much more information on how to tag things on [wiki.openstreetmap.org](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/).

Comment: g day dear tomh - thx for all your advices - i will follow them